# Find element in array of jsonb documents by value as case insensitive

Tags: postgresql

Assume I have userinfo table with person column containing the following jsonb object:

```
{
    "skills": [
        {
            "name": "php"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python"
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to get Python skill i would write the following query

`select * from userinfo
where person -> 'skills' @> '[{"name":"Python"}]'`

It works well, but if specify `'[{"name":"python"}]'` as lower case it doesn't return me what i want.

How can i write case insensitive query there?

**Postgre version is 11.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that when unnesting with an `exists` predicate:

```
select u.*
from userinfo u
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(u.person -> 'skills') as s(j)
              -- make sure to only do this for rows that actually contain an array
              where jsonb_typeof(u.person -> 'skills') = 'array'
                and lower(s.j ->> 'name') = 'python');
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/XKVUA73952

Comment: SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar

Comment: sure... they could be as null... sorry for that

Comment: @Pyrejkee then your sample data does not match your real data. This does work with the sample you have given (see the online example)

Comment: trouble was at my side... but it works a little bit slowly if i add group statements (i said the same to previous author) 4 seconds instead of 1 seconds (when there is no group statement). is it possible to empower query performance?

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d976962656f8641d47196170c55f2e70)

AFAIK there is no in-built JSON function for that. So, you have to convert the JSON-String to lower case (meaning casting into type `text`, lower-case it, recast it into type `jsonb`):

```
WHERE lower(person::text)::jsonb -> 'skills' @> '[{"name":"python"}]'
```

Comment: Actually it works, but there is one drawback - if i apply group by statement the query is being executed for 15 sec instead of 1 sec (when i'm not applying group by statement)

Comment: Yes this could be. Maybe the other solution could work, but the query planner shows lower cost values for my solution (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b96da347574042e0f86159e1f0f99bc7). But it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select 1 as id, 'fname' as firstname, 'sname' as surname, jsonb_array_elements('{
    "skills": [{"name": "php"},{"name": "Python"}]}'::jsonb->'skills') skill) p
where p.skill->>'name' ilike 'python';
```

to suit the tables in the question it'd be something like

```
select * from (select *, jsonb_array_elements(person->'skills') skill from userinfo) u
where u.skill->>'name' ilike 'python';
```

Just a note, this will return multiple entries for the same userinfo if you start looking for multiple skills .. if you use the above, you'd want to group by the fields you want returned or select distinct id, username etc.

like (assuming there's an id column in the userinfo table)

select distinct id from (select *, jsonb_array_elements(person->'skills') skill from userinfo) u
where u.skill->>'name' ilike 'python' or u.skill->>'name' ilike 'php';

it all depends what you want to do